# How to share Thymeleaf templates across domain

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm developing some Spring applications using Spring Boot 1.4.1 and spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency. I wish to share my Thymeleaf templates (such as header and footer) on my webserver to be able to include them in my applications. The easiest way to achieve this would be to include server root relative link to my templates in each of my apps. This way, my apps will be portable and I can get it to work seamlessly on all my environments (dev, test, prod).

From my perspective, this seems not to be a big deal since the server-relative URLs are already taken into account by Thymeleaf

```
<th:block th:replace="@{~/my/share/header}" />
```

However I can't get it to work. I always get an error like

> Error resolving template "/my/share/header", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

I can confirm that my template is available because http://localhost/my/share/header.html is responding correctly (btw: I'm using Apache httpd to host my apps so I'm using the same port).

I've also tried to add ".html" at the end of the URL or implement the URLTemplateResolver (see below) but unfortunately, nothing seems to work.

```
@Bean
public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    UrlTemplateResolver templateResolver = new UrlTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return templateResolver; 
}
```

Does someone knows how to embed templates using server root relative URLs?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's no way to achieve this in the current version of Thymeleaf as you can see in this [GitHub](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/554) post. My workaround is to use the UrlTemplateResolver as described in the initial post and add a variable in my Spring Boot project (application.properties). This way, I can manage different URL depending of my deployment environments.